# Add spacing at the end of inline mathmode \(...\)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

The language I use for certain files look much better if there is a small space `\,` after each inline equation, like this:

```
\(...\)   % BAD  spacing
\(...\,\) % GOOD spacing
```

But it's not quite productive to add the `\,` to every inline math equation. So is there a way to make this a default setting, in the preamble maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what benefit you get from adding space after each formula.

Anyway, the space should be indeed added *after* the formula, not before it ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\)\relax % undefine \)
\DeclareRobustCommand\){%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    \ifinner
      $\thinspace % add a kern after the formula
    \else
      \@badmath
    \fi
  \else
    \@badmath
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a+b$ xyz % for comparison

\(a+b\) xyz

\bigskip

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% tight to the box

% for comparison
\fbox{\parbox{4.8cm}{This line ends with math $a+b\,$ and text follows}}

\medskip

\fbox{\parbox{4.8cm}{This line ends with math \(a+b\) and text follows}}

\end{document}
```

The first two lines show that the space is actually added when the `\(...\)` syntax is added. The two boxes show that if one adds it before closing the formula, the space is not removed at line breaks.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a master, but for safety concerns I'm going to go with this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the advantage of such setting. However, maybe this helps

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand\){\,$}
\begin{document}

\noindent
$ y=f(x) $x \\
$ y=f(x) $ x \\
\( y=f(x) \)x

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\)` does much more than `$`.

Comment: sure, which is not important if he/she uses it only for something like above. If not, then he/she can simply overwrite the original definition: `\DeclareRobustCommand\){\relax\ifmmode\ifinner\,$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}`